# What team do I need to talk to about deleting a page on help.ubuntu.com?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I would like to delete a junky page from help.ubuntu.com, but it seems I do not have access to the page, what team should I talk to to have the page removed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't just delete a page, it needs to be tagged for deletion so the documentation team can review it.

Information on deleting pages:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide/DeletingAndRenaming

Simply putting this tag on top of the page you want deleted puts it in the editor queue to be reviewed:

```
<<Include(Tag/Deletion)>>
```