# What steps should I take when I find wrong information in the Ubuntu wiki pages?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I sometimes end up in a Ubuntu wiki page when looking for information. Most of the times that information is a bit out dated, which is fine, others its mostly wrong or does not reflect the actuality.

If I find information on the Ubuntu wiki that is very wrong or even considered dangerous what steps should I take to try to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like Ask Ubuntu, if something is wrong, fix it. :)

If the page is so bad it can't be fixed, consider tagging it for deletion:

- [What team do I need to talk to about deleting a page on help.ubuntu.com?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42503/what-team-do-i-need-to-talk-to-about-deleting-a-page-on-help-ubuntu-com)

Comment: As with other projects, the Ubuntu wiki is a community project, if you find something you can improve don't hold back. Imagine what we could do with our user base if everyone contributed just a little ?