# How to suggest that a wiki page be deleted?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What team do I need to talk to about deleting a page on help.ubuntu.com?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42503/what-team-do-i-need-to-talk-to-about-deleting-a-page-on-help-ubuntu-com)

**Background**: There's a [video clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nto7bdqxicI) on the topic but it isn't clear who is being addressed.

What can a user of Ubuntu do in regard to a wiki page like this one: [Ubuntu EyeCandy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEyeCandy). Even though it's prominently flagged as *applying to an unsupported version of Ubuntu*, it comes up as the top-most result in a Google search with "ubuntu mouse cursor color" with a date of 22 May 2012.

Would this page merit deletion? How do I tag it for deletion as suggested in [What steps should I take when I find wrong information in the Ubuntu wiki pages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106979/what-steps-should-i-take-when-i-find-wrong-information-in-the-ubuntu-wiki-pages?rq=1). I have a Launchpad account but I'm not seeing a **tag for deletion** option on the wiki page after signing in.

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42503/what-team-do-i-need-to-talk-to-about-deleting-a-page-on-help-ubuntu-com

Comment: If you make that an answer I'll accept it (providing this question isn't closed as a duplicate).

Comment: Okay, that answer leads to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tag#Deletion) which suggests three possible criteria which I paraphrase as: spam, malicious content, or not being useful to **any** Ubuntu user. For the specific page in question, even the third criterion may not apply because someone on an "unsupported" release may decide to add eye candy. So I'm going to let this one pass.

Comment: @vasa1 I would rather close this question as duplicate because it kinda covers the same grounds than answer it. :) You do agree that it pretty much is the same thing right?

Comment: Not an issue at all :)